# Cell magic `%%` not found after loading and connecting in Jupyter

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, ipython, jupyter

I'm trying to use sqlite in Jupyter and so far I have done

```
%load_ext sql
%sql sqlite:///Newsvendor.db
```

in the first cell and

```
%% sql
select * from demand
```

in the second cell. But in the second cell I'm getting the error "UsageError: Cell magic `%%` not found."

I'm doing this after installing ipython-sql. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try deleting the space between the second `%` and `sql`? [Examples here](https://github.com/catherinedevlin/ipython-sql) and [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/jupyter-magics-with-sql-921370099589) have no space. The show it as `%%sql`.